# How to create a loop to iterate a join with pyspark

Tags: python, loops, join, pyspark

I'm working on Databricks and I have a dataframe that contains a list of BOM (bill of materials): the structure of the dataframe is reported in the example below, where identifier is the code of the "father" product (a finished product) and component is the code of the "son" product (that can be a semi-finished product or a raw material). If the component is a semi-finished product you can find it also in the identifier list, with its components (but I have no indication in the dataframe that tells me the type of product, if finished, semifinished or raw).

```
  identifier   component
  xxxx         yyyy
  xxxx         zzzz
  xxxx         aaaa
  aaaa         bbbb
  aaaa         cccc
  bbbb         dddd
  bbbb         eeee
  cccc         ffff
  cccc         mmmm
  ffff         aaaa
  ffff         gggg
  ffff         hhhh
  hhhh         iiii
  hhhh         jjjj
```

In the example above there are two final products (xxxx and ffff). xxxx has as components yyyy, zzzz and aaaa. aaaa should be a semi-finished product because it is also listed in the identifier column and it is composed by cccc and dddd. cccc and dddd are also semifinished products because they are listed in the identifier column and are composed by dddd, eeee, ffff and mmmm (that should be raw materials because they are not in the identifier column). The second final product ffff is composed by aaaa (semi-finished product also used for xxxx), gggg (raw material) and hhhh (semi-finished product, composed by iiii and jjjj, raw materials). 
I have to filter this dataframe following a list of products that is provided by me by business, that only contains final products: let's suppose that I have to select only xxxx (ffff is not in the list). The problem is that if I filter xxxx I lose the information connected to the semi-finished products (if I filter the dataframe selecting only identifier xxxx I obtain 3 rows, but what I have to do is to find a way to keep also aaaa, bbbb and cccc, and for each of them also the detail of their components). So the final filtered dataframe should be

```
    identifier   component
  xxxx         yyyy
  xxxx         zzzz
  xxxx         aaaa
  aaaa         bbbb
  aaaa         cccc
  bbbb         dddd
  bbbb         eeee
  cccc         ffff
  cccc         mmmm
```

I'm trying to figure out how to solve this problem with a loop (the real dataframe is obviously bigger, roughly 13000 rows) but I can't find a good starting point (I'm not a python expert). Does anyone as some good suggestion, documentation or a snippet to use as a starting point?

Answer (score 0):

> if I filter the dataframe selecting only identifier xxxx I obtain 3
>   rows, but what I have to do is to find a way to keep also aaaa, bbbb
>   and cccc

<s>Don't you mean, you have to find a way of keeping `yyyy`, `zzzz` and `aaaa`, since these are the products that `xxxx` depends on? Clear this up and explain a bit more about how you're getting the final filtered dataframe (I'm getting a different result), and I'll be happy to help.</s>

I'm still happy to help, but I still don't understand how you arrived at your final filtered dataframe.

So you select `xxxx` and receive the three associated components `yyyy`, `zzzz` and `aaaa`. Then what? You get the associated components for those three components, and you do this recursively until you arrive at base materials? That doesn't reflect what's in your final filtered dataframe, though.

**EDIT** If I'm understanding the question correctly, here's what I came up with (I don't use pandas regularly, so I wouldn't be surprised if there are pandas features which could make this cuter):

```
def main():

    import pandas as pd
    from queue import Queue

    df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", names=["identifier", "component"])

    result_df = pd.DataFrame()

    selected_identifier = "xxxx"
    identifier_queue = Queue()
    identifier_queue.put(selected_identifier)
    previously_seen_identifiers = set()

    while not identifier_queue.empty():
        current_identifier = identifier_queue.get()
        if current_identifier in previously_seen_identifiers:
            continue
        previously_seen_identifiers.add(current_identifier)
        current_df = df.loc[df["identifier"] == current_identifier]
        result_df = result_df.append(current_df)
        components = current_df[["component"]]["component"].tolist()
        for component in components:
            identifier_queue.put(component)

    print(result_df)

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Here's how it works:

- Create a queue (it could also be a stack) of identifiers which still
  need to be processed. Initially the only identifier to be processed
  the final product we select (`xxxx` in this case).
- While the queue is not empty, get the next identifier and remove it
  from the queue, create a dataframe from the original dataframe
  containing only the components on which the current identifier
  depends on, and append this sub-dataframe to the `result_df`
  dataframe. Before we start the next iteration we take the associated
  components on which the current identifier depends and add them to
  our queue of unprocessed identifiers.
- Before the loop, we also created a `set()` to keep track of all the
  identifiers we've seen so far. In the loop, if the current identifier
  has already been seen, we ignore it and move on to the next
  identifier. This was put in place because some products appear to
  have circular dependencies.

Let me know if this is what you were thinking of.

Comment: Hi, I mean that I have to find a way to keep also the products that xxxx depends on. If I join the dataframe with the list of identifier provided me by business (only with final product xxxx) I only obtain the three rows with xxxx, but what I'm looking for is to keep in the final results also the products connected to xxxx (aaaa, bbbb, cccc). I hope it's more clear

Comment: Let's call them `x` instead of `xxxx` and so on, shall we? `x` depends on `y`, `z` and `a`. `y` and `z` appear to be base-materials because they do not appear in the identifier column. `a` however appears in the identifier column, which means it's a semi-finished product. `a` depends on `b` and `c`, both of which are also semi-finished products. You keep doing this until you have no more products which depend on semi-finished products, yes? If that is true, then why is your filtered dataframe example missing some products? Do you only go down a certain depth?

Comment: Sorry to comment twice in a row, but I've updated my original post with my solution - assuming of course that I've understood the problem correctly.